# Get country phone prefix with react-native-localize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to get country phone prefix with react-native-localize? I can get country code, language code and may others things but I can't seem to get the phone prefix!

For example, in Spain prefix is +34, in US I think its +1

Comment: There is a website, [countrycode.org](https://countrycode.org/) that list all the phone prefixes based on the country. So, you could create a lookup from that. Either by having a database table or a JSON file. Then, based on the results given by `react-native-localize`, you can check the lookup table or JSON, then obtain the phone prefix.

Comment: There are sites such as [numverify](https://numverify.com/documentation) that allows you to do a REST call and get the information you need such as the phone prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js) for it. For example:

```js
import getCountryCallingCode from 'libphonenumber-js'

getCountryCallingCode('RU') // returns '7'
getCountryCallingCode('IL') // returns '972'
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to parse phone numbers, but a way to get the country code prefix from the user's locale.

Comment: @MehrdadMoradi I see just changed my answer with proper function

Comment: I checked the package from Google and it does not support `getCountryCallingCode`, however the other package you suggested contains this method. I suggested an edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an npm library such as [`country-telephone-data`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-telephone-data)

Here is an example of how to do it with `expo-localization` ... but the principle would be very similar with `react-native-localize`

```
import {allCountries} from 'country-telephone-data';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export const CountryDialCode = () => {
  const [dialCode, setDialCode] = useState<string>();
  
  // This sets a state variable for dial code with an async call that looks up the localisation region and then uses that to look up the country dial code.
  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountryTelephoneCode = async () => {
      const {region} = await Localization.getLocalizationAsync();
      if (!region) return;
      const country = allCountries.find((country) => country.iso2 === region.toLowerCase());

      console.log(country);
      const _dialCode = country?.dialCode;
      setDialCode(_dialCode);
    };
    getCountryTelephoneCode();
  }, []);

  return <Text>{dialCode}</Text>;
};
```